# How to remove a duplicated list traversal in Java

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I am creating a solitare card game, which stores cards in arraylist. 
I want to create two methods which check for movement and play for player.

One boolean function which goes through the ArrayList and checks if there is any possible move. This method returns true if there is possibility.

The second one makes move. It also goes through the ArrayList and checks if there is any possible move, makes this move and stops working. To stop it I used return true. But I think that its not good way.

And two functions are very similiar, code is duplicated. How to fix it?
Should this method which looks is any move possible return boolean value or two numbers of cards (a and b) which could be moved?

```
public boolean makeMove() {
    int a = 0; //index of one card
    int b; //index of second card
    for (b = getSize() - 1; b > 0; b--) {
        for (a = 0; a < b; a++) {
            if (isCorrectMove(a, b)) {
                swap(a, b); //makes move
                return true; //exit after move
            }
        }
    }
    return false; //if there was no move
}

public boolean isPossibleAnyMove() {int a = 0; //index of one card
        int b; //index of second card
        for (b = getSize() - 1; b > 0; b--) {
            for (a = 0; a < b; a++) {
                if (isCorrectMove(a, b)) {
                    return true; //returns true if there was a move
                }
            }
        }
        return false; //if there was no move
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean someName(boolean shouldSwap) {
    int a = 0; //index of one card
    int b; //index of second card
    for (b = getSize() - 1; b > 0; b--) {
        for (a = 0; a < b; a++) {
            if (isCorrectMove(a, b)) {
                if (shouldSwap)
                    swap(a, b); //makes move
                return true; //exit after move
            }
        }
    }
    return false; //if there was no move
}
```

If the swap is the only difference this is a possible way to combine these two functions in a single one...

Comment: thanks but is it correct with object oriented programming methods? doesnt this function do too much?

Comment: Yeah, it does sound to me like this breaks cohesion.

Answer (score 6):

You could create a function for finding the first correct move; This function would return a object containing values `a` and `b` of the correct move or `null` if there is no correct move.

```
private static class Move {

    int a, b;

    Move(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

}

private Move findFirstCorrectMove() {
    int a = 0; //index of one card
    int b; //index of second card
    for (b = getSize() - 1; b > 0; b--) {
        for (a = 0; a < b; a++) {
            if (isCorrectMove(a, b)) {
                return new Move(a,b);
            }
        }
    }
    return null; //if there was no move
}

public boolean makeMove() {
    Move move = findFirstCorrectMove();
    if (move != null) {
        swap(move.a, move.b);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isPossibleAnyMove() {
    return findFirstCorrectMove() != null;
}
```

Of course you could simply use a `int[]` array instead of creating a new `Move` class.

---

You could also use the strategy pattern to handle the move. I hope a few java 8 features in the code don't bother you:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MoveConsumer {
    void acceptMove(int a, int b);
}

private boolean findFirstCorrectMove(MoveConsumer moveConsumer) {
    int a = 0; //index of one card
    int b; //index of second card
    for (b = getSize() - 1; b > 0; b--) {
        for (a = 0; a < b; a++) {
            if (isCorrectMove(a, b)) {
                moveConsumer.acceptMove(a, b);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false; //if there was no move
}

public boolean makeMove() {
    return findFirstCorrectMove(this::swap); // assuming here that swap is non-static
}

public boolean isPossibleAnyMove() {
    return findFirstCorrectMove((a, b) -> {});
}
```

Comment: Wow,  this is almost exactly what I suggested, although you beat me to it. I'll remove my answer.

Comment: Ha ha, it looks like we both wrote the same answer. You beat me to it.

Comment: You may also consider Java's 8 Optional or Google Guava Optional for the findCorrectMove method instead of using nulls.

Comment: OK. thanks very much. Could also be a Strategy design pattern used here somehow?

Comment: Thats nice, but how does this stategy patters works?

Comment: @siema: I assume you don't know about lambda expressions and method references yet? These work similar to anonymus classes that implement `MoveConsumer`. The bodys of the `acceptMove` methods would be `{swap(a,b);}` and `{}`; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make a single function that takes a boolean to control the behaviour.

```
public boolean CheckOrmakeMove(boolean swapBool) {
        int a = 0; //index of one card
        int b; //index of second card
        for (b = getSize() - 1; b > 0; b--) {
            for (a = 0; a < b; a++) {
                if (isCorrectMove(a, b)) {
                    if(swapBool)
                    swap(a, b); //makes move
                    return true; //exit after move
                }
            }
        }
        return false; //if there was no move
    }
```